# Generating very large XML files in Python?

Tags: python, xml, lxml

Does anyone know of a memory efficient way to generate very large xml files (e.g. 100-500 MiB) in Python?

I've been utilizing **lxml**, but memory usage is through the roof.

Comment: Is this a good idea ? What's going to *consume* such a file ?

Comment: 500MiB XML file? Yikes - if my XML files got to 500MiB I'd consider a more efficient file format! :-)

Comment: How complicated is the output document? Where are you getting the input data from? How complicated are the input-to-output transformations?

Comment: Have you considered whether you can break it into more manageable pieces and use Xinclude ? Depends, I guess, on what sort of process is going to be consuming this big file, as the point would be not to process the xincludes into a large file at the end, but to have the final consumer process process the xincludes on the fly. Don't know if that model would fit into your workflow, but if it did, it could make it more manageable. ( I have trouble imagining what kind of process would be the consumer of a 500MB xml file! ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Perhaps you could use a templating engine instead of generating/building the xml yourself?

[Genshi](http://genshi.edgewall.org/) for example is xml-based and supports streaming output. A very basic example:

```
from genshi.template import MarkupTemplate

tpl_xml = '''
<doc xmlns:py="http://genshi.edgewall.org/">
<p py:for="i in data">${i}</p>
</doc>
'''

tpl = MarkupTemplate(tpl_xml)
stream = tpl.generate(data=xrange(10000000))

with open('output.xml', 'w') as f:
    stream.render(out=f)
```

It might take a while, but memory usage remains low.

The same example for the [Mako](http://www.makotemplates.org/) templating engine (not "natively" xml), but a lot faster:

```
from mako.template import Template
from mako.runtime import Context

tpl_xml = '''
<doc>
% for i in data:
<p>${i}</p>
% endfor
</doc>
'''

tpl = Template(tpl_xml)

with open('output.xml', 'w') as f:
    ctx = Context(f, data=xrange(10000000))
    tpl.render_context(ctx)
```

The last example ran on my laptop for about 20 seconds, producing a (admittedly very simple) 151 MB xml file, no memory problems at all. (according to Windows task manager it remained constant at about 10MB)

Depending on your needs, this might be a friendlier and faster way of generating xml than using SAX etc... Check out the docs to see what you can do with these engines (there are others as well, I just picked out these two as examples)

Comment: Fantastic idea! This is definitely one worth considering.

Answer (score 2):

The only sane way to generate so large an XML file is line by line, which means printing while running a state machine, and **lots** of testing.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, you've got to avoid having to build the entire tree ( whether DOM or etree or whatever ) in memory. But the best way depends on the source of your data and how complicated and interlinked the structure of your output is.

If it's big because it's got thousands of instances of fairly independent items, then you can generate the outer wrapper, and then build trees for each item and then serialize each fragment to the output.

If the fragments aren't so independent, then you'll need to do some extra bookkeeping -- like maybe manage a database of generated ids & idrefs.

I would break it into 2 or 3 parts: a sax event producer, an output serializer
eating sax events, and optionally, if it seems easier to work with some independent pieces as objects or trees, something to build those objects and then turn them into sax events for the serializer.

Maybe you could just manage it all as direct text output, instead of dealing with sax events: that depends on how complicated it is.

This may also be a good place to use python generators as a way of streaming the output without having to build large structures in memory.

Comment: Hmm, yes it will have thousands of instances of fairly independent items. 

I think I might that approach. Thanks.

Comment: The templating approach suggested above is probably easier  -- especially if the separate object/chunks are small enough to handle.
Running the SAX producer / consumer pair as co-routines using python generators would be the alternative if things didn't easily break into small enough chunks.

Answer (score 0):

If your document is very regular (such as a bunch of database records, all in the same format) you could use my own "xe" library.

http://home.avvanta.com/~steveha/xe.html

The xe library was designed for generating syndication feeds (Atom, RSS, etc.) and I think it is easy to use.  I need to update it for Python 2.6, and I haven't yet, sorry about that.

Comment: Very nice. Is this more memory efficient than using lxml?

Comment: Not sure.  I haven't looked at lxml yet.  If you are holding all your data at once, then you are holding at least 500 MiB no matter what.  But if you are writing stuff in a loop, you could re-use the same xe data structures, which would save memory.  But maybe you could do the same thing with lxml?